# What are the other applications of javascript engine other than web browser

Tags: javascript

I was exploring [javascript Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) and there types and came across this phrase (inside wiki article):

> "*Although there are several uses for a JavaScript engine, it is most commonly used in web browsers.*"

But above linked article has information and history related to its web browser application only. So, I searched a lot but could only able to find it's use in **node.js** for server side scripting. But, I am still curious to know if someone knows any other potential application of js-engine.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a way to run software. It's useful anywhere you want to run software. A list would be massively long.

Answer (score 0):

For, example, Node.js - JavaScript on a webserver.

Also there are solutions for different tasks, even AI and neuronetworks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is also commonly used for scripting.
For example you can use it in order to create routines for administration and data management in [Mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/).

You can use JavaScript for advanced [NGINX configuration](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/nginScript/) scenarios.
Javascript can be used for game (Unity) and application development (UWP) etc